# What would be the best way to upload data with Azure Data Factory to Azure Database

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory, azure-sql-database

I'm looking for the best way to upload files to a Azure SQL Database.
We have to use Azure Data Factory as at this moment we are not allowed to use Azure VM's with SSIS.
Each day we are upload 1,5Gb of XML files.
Currently we we are uploading the to a Blob storage and with a Copy activity we are uploading them into the DB.
But this takes up to 2,5 hours.
What would be a better/faster concept to do this ?

Any Suggestions ?

Comment: Have you looked at ADFv2? You can deploy an SSIS package to Azure

Comment: With your data factory, are you running your activities in parallel or series? Could you increase the db "size" while the ADF is running and then drop it back down - often it works out cheaper to have a process run for a short time on an expensive machine than for a long time on a cheaper machine.

Comment: Azure SQL Database has the ability to [load directly from Blob storage](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2017/02/23/loading-files-from-azure-blob-storage-into-azure-sql-database/), so you could load it straight to a table with a column of `xml` datatype and process from there.  Can you post some sample xml and expected results please?

Comment: As posted beneath, at this moment our company policy blocks me on having a VM in Azure. So ADF2 still needs one to run the SSIS jobs.

Comment: Nick, how would you increase the DB in the ADF ? That would be a greta solution if I could do this in the ADF flow.

Comment: @Harry Leboeuf - you can't resize the db within the ADF but you can create an Azure Automation routine to resize it; schedule this to run 20-30 mins before your ADF starts and then give it a reasonable buffer after the current usual end time to reset the size. Monitor it for a bit to see where to adjust the timings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it dropped to 35 minutes.
Just by using several storage accounts (5) and split the data over the 5 accounts.
5 ADF pipelines uploding all into the same staging table.
Some where huge files, but we had over 100.000 small files from 2 up to 100K.
This worked out fine for us.

We noticed that the DTU's never went up to their limit so we thought that the DB was not the problem, by firts splitting into 2 we saw DTU rising a bit more. we continued on that path....

Answer (score 0):

You can use the bcp utility to import your data into an instance of SQL Server as explained in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/examples-of-bulk-import-and-export-of-xml-documents-sql-server). From there, you can use the [Azure Data Synchronization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-get-started-sql-data-sync) tool to synchronize your Azure SQL Database with your SQL Server Database. This may provide a faster execution time.

Comment: Would be great but no way at this moment i can get out firewall guys to open port 1433. We are a public service and have our restrictions by the gouvernment. Silly I know but I have to deal with it.